# Square brackets in PgAdmin 4 for null values

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

In pgAdmin 4, the column value is seen as a square bracket [...] instead of an empty value.
The column data type is character(4) and name is carr_desig_icao_cd. Database is postgreSql.

How to avoid the square brackets? I tried pgAdmin 4 preferences but no luck.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Output from psql is as below:

[image]

Comment: What do get if you select from the table in `psql`?

Comment: No square brackets using psql. Thanks

Comment: What is the actual output when select from `psql`? Include in your question. Are you sure the data type for the column is `char(4)`? I can not replicate in `pgAdmin`.

Comment: Yes, data type is character(4). The actual output from psql shows no data for the null values.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be something to do with converting to_char?

Here are results of my testing.

This query produced no brackets and dots:

```
select at1.score
```

This query produced brackets and dots

```
select to_char(at1.score, '999')
```

I noticed when this was downloaded and opened in Excel, there were no brackets but three spaces at the start of the column.

This query removed the brackets and dots in PgAdmin and removed the spaces after downloading to Excel:

```
select replace(to_char(at1.score, '999'), ' ', '')
```

Just noting also that this was a sub query as part of a bigger query that looked a bit like this:

```
select
cm.course_id
, us.user_id
, gm.title
, (select replace(to_char(at1.score * 20, '999'), ' ', '')  || '%   ' || to_char(at1.attempt_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') from attempt at1 where at1.pk1 = gg.highest_attempt_pk1)
from 
etc (joins of course_main cm, users us, gradebook_main gm, gradebook_grade gg, attempt at)
```

[This screenshot shows before and after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtdyV.png)